# Swift Comparable Protocol great than method

Tags: swift, swift4, comparable

```
class Test {
    var count: Int;
    init(count: Int) {
       self.count = count;
    }
}


extension Test: Comparable {
    static func <(lhs: Test, rhs: Test) -> Bool {
        return lhs.count > rhs.count
    }
}
```

When I write this extension everything work okay  but when i change `<` to `>` compiler error return

> Type 'Test' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'

Comparable extension required write `<` this function 
What is this reason?

Comment: *"When I write this extension everything work okay"* – No. That code does not compile. Did you omit something?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/comparable) for `Comparable`, you can see that it inherits from `Equatable`.

`Equatable` requires `==` to be implemented:

```
static func ==(lhs: Test, rhs: Test) -> Bool {
    return lhs.count == rhs.count
}
```

I should also mention that `count` does not have an initial value. So you need to add an initializer for `Test` or a initial value to `count`.

EDIT:

If you look at the docs for `Comparable`, you'll find this bit:

> Types with Comparable conformance implement the less-than operator (<)
>   and the equal-to operator (==). These two operations impose a strict
>   total order on the values of a type, in which exactly one of the
>   following must be true for any two values a and b:
>
> - a == b
> - a < b
> - b < a

So you must implement `<` and `==` but `>` is unnecessary. That's why it doesn't work when you only have `>`.